# cpan shell errors - ActivePerl 5.24.3

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, activeperl

I have just installed Activestate Perl 5.24.3 on Windows 7 PC.

I am able to instal with ppm. Installed also CPAN.

But - I fail to launch the CPAN shell on CMD (DOS command line).

Here is whan I get when trying to invoke the cpan shell in CMD:

```
C:\Users\orenm>cpan
Cwd object version 3.63_01 does not match bootstrap parameter 3.74 at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 211.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/File/Spec/Win32.pm line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl64/site/lib/File/Spec/Win32.pm line5.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/File/Spec.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/CPAN.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl64/site/lib/CPAN.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/App/Cpan.pm line 288.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl64/site/lib/App/Cpan.pm line 288.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Perl64\site\bin/cpan line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl64\site\bin/cpan line 7.

C:\Users\orenm>
```

This also happens when trying to use the C:\Perl64\bin\cpan.bat .

Comment: Cwd has a pure Perl component (Cwd.pm) and a binary component (Cwd.dll). The two components being loaded are from different versions of the module. You have a messed up installation, or you are telling Perl to look for modules in places where it shouldn't.

Comment: Where do I check it? - I mean if I tell Perl to look for modules in places where it shouldn't.

Comment: Are the `PERL5LIB` or `PERLLIB` env vars set?

Comment: No, I do not see these env vars.  

I am looking on: 
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System
System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Comment: More definitely, just type `set | find "PERL"` from the cmd in the console from which you run `cpan`. It's probably not going to give you anything different though, leaving the other option: A messed up Perl directory.

Comment: You are right, it gives nothing:  
`C:\Users\orenm>  set | find "PERL"

C:\Users\orenm>`

This means... what?  Do I need to do 'Remove' and install again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174381/discussion-between-oren-maurer-and-ikegami).

Comment: Do `where perl` and `where cpan` refer to the same place?

Answer (score 1):

Well - solved. :) 
As ikegami noted - I probably messed up the installation.

I have managed to solve this by doing the following:

1. Choosing the "Remove" option of the ActivePerl installer,
2. Move aside the C:\Perl64\ directory,  I mean - rename it.
3. I verified the I don't have Perl in the system path variables. 
   and:
4. Activated the ActivePerl installer exe ("ActivePerl-5.24.3.2404-MSWin32-x64-404865.exe"), choosing the typical installation.